# watchOS 3 Using WCSession in class shared between device and watch

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-3, wcsession

My app depends on constant communication between the watch and the device. I want to use a singleton to manage all messaging and session states. I want to use inheritance to further customize this behavior separately on the watch and on the device. I want the parent class to be a WCSessionDelegate, but the WCSession library exists for iOS and watchOS and each has separate delegate functions. Is there a way to include both sets of functions in the super class? Right now the compiler treats the file as one or the other even though it is a part of both the app and watch targets.

[Functions are marked as unavailable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv28B.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, you can use compiler directives like this (Swift3.1):

```
#if os(iOS)
    <methods avaliable on iOS's Watch Connectivity framework>
#elseif os(watchOS)
    <methods avaliable on watchOS's Watch Connectivity framework>
#endif
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!